# Error reading an excel file in golang

Tags: excel, go

I was trying the below code but I get an error

> **"multiple-value cell.String() in single-value context"**

**Code**

```
 package main
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
 )
 func main() { 
     excelFileName := "test.xlsx"
     xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFileName)
     if err != nil {

     }
 for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
    for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
          for _, cell := range row.Cells {
            fmt.Printf("%s ", cell.String(), "123")
  }
            fmt.Printf("\n")
  }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
for _, cell := range row.Cells {
    fmt.Printf("%s ", cell.String(), "123")
}
```

to

```
for _, cell := range row.Cells {
    val, _ := cell.String()
    fmt.Printf("%s ", val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a function that returns multiple values as a single argument (to `fmt.Printf()`)

If you don't think you will get any errors, you can just assign it to `_` and ignore it, but you really should be prepared to handle the error.  This is why Go forces you to use variables and why it doesn't automatically discard other return values (like the error from `cell.String()`)

```
val, err := cell.String()
if err != nil {
    // handle the error
}
fmt.Printf("%s ", val) // you had an extra arg of "123"?
```

Comment: I have installed the teaeg xls package and i have saved my file in the same folder "src\github.com\tealeg\xlsx\<file.go>"    Yet i get the error that "readexcel.go:4:1: found packages xlsx (cell.go) and main (readexcel.go) in E:\RI
L\Golang\src\github.com\tealeg\xlsx"

Comment: You don't need to put your file in the xlsx package, the imports at the top will give you access to those.

Comment: it means i can put my file in any folder (as specified in GOPATH) right ??? I have started GO today so my questions may seem funny.

Comment: @IramKhan, yes, you can put it in any folder on your gopath.  The [golang.org docs](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH) have some more info